# Vuetify Select Component and Cypress

Tags: vuetify.js, cypress

I have a component with a Vuetify Select component:

```
<v-select
  :items="corporations"
  label="Corporation name"
  data-test="corporation-name"
  outlined
></v-select>
```

And I want to simulate a selection with a Cypress test:

`cy.get('[data-test="corporation-name"]').select('Thorgate');`

Unfortunately, I can't and I have this error message:

```
CypressError: cy.select() can only be called on a <select>. Your subject is a: <input data-test="corporation-name" id="input-13" readonly="readonly" type="text" aria-readonly="false" autocomplete="off">
```

I have also try to enter the value with a `type()`but Cypress told me

```
CypressError: Timed out retrying: cy.type() failed because this element is readonly:
```

Any idea, please?

Comment: The error message should mention to try the `{ force: true }` option to type into the readonly input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors are pretty self-explanatory.

- You're trying to apply a `cy.select()` method to an `<input>` tag, when you need a `<select>` tag
- You're trying to `.type()` into a `<input readonly>`

`cy.select()` can only be applied to a `<select>` tag. If your v-select component renders a **"custom select that is a bunch a dynamic divs and inputs INSTEAD of a select"**, then you need to create a custom Cypress command to handle a `cy.customSelect()` behavior. For example, it would: click on the main wrapper, find a option by typing words, and click on it... therefore selecting the option

For the second one, because your input is readonly, you can try to use {force: true} in your options when typing (`cy.type("text", {force: true})`

Answer (score 1):

A little bit late, but, I hope this can help someone. ;)

The easier way I found to solve the problem with vuetify v-select, is using {force: true}, as stated by Jordan, and "pressing enter" at the end of string, like so:

```
cy.get('[data-test="corporation-name"]').type('Thorgate{enter}',{force:true});
```

https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/type#Arguments

Answer (score 0):

I am using Cypress 13.2.0, the force type method throws error `cy.type() failed because it requires a valid typeable element.`

So far the best way I found is using the following, wish there is a cleaner way to achieve this.

```js
cy.wait(500)
  .then(_ => {
    cy.get('[data-test=corporation-name]').trigger('mousedown').type('t')
  })
```